# SQLAlchemy Declarative get object by secondary attribute

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a model as follows:

```py
def myModel:
   train =   db.Text()
   id =      db.Integer(db.PrimaryKey) 
   version = db.Integer(default=0)
   #other irrelevant values
```

Now, in a specific api call I have access to a given id, and I want to select the `max(version)` from `myModel` BY that id's train value. I can't for the life of me figure out how.

E.g. if i have the following table:

```
+-----+---------+------+
| id  | version | train|
+-----+---------+------+
|    3|       1 | asdsf| <--
|   17|       2 | asdsf|
|   19|       3 | asdsf| <--
|   21|       3 | gfddd|
+-----+---------+------+
```

and in my api i have the id `3` available my goal is to get the object corresponding to id `19`.
I imagine taking the route via the `train` value is the easiest as thats what identifying subsequent changes.
Using declarative, I've gotten as far as the following:

```py
s1 = session.query(func.max(myModel.version).label("max"), myModel.train).group_by(myModel.train).subquery()
s2 = myModel.query.join(s1, and_(myModel.version = s1.c.max_version))
```

But this returns every max per train - I dont know how to go from ID -> train and then from there to max(version) ..
The easy way would be to just issue a call for the object,  fetch the train and from there find out the max of version, but I was hoping there'd be a way to do this in one call?

Comment: Something like `s1 = session.query(func.max(myModel.version).label("max")).filter_by(train='asdsf').one_or_none` ought to work.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for the reply. I think I wasn't clear enough, because im not sure what the `train` will be, I only have the `id` at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result by using a subquery to get the value of `train` using the `id`.

In SQL you would do it like this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(version)
  FROM Table1
  WHERE train = (SELECT train 
                   FROM Table1 
                   WHERE id = 17);
```

The equivalent using SQLAlchemy is:

```py
subq = session.query(MyModel.train).filter_by(id=17).scalar()
m = session.query(sa.func.max(MyModel.version).label('max')).filter_by(train=subq).scalar()
print('Max version is', m)
```